# raw_input A = 10, if A == 10 giving false: Python

Tags: python, if-statement, raw-input

```
A = raw_input("5 + 5 =")

if A == 10:
    print "$"
elif A <> 10:
    print "!"
```

when I input 10 I also get "!" why?

Comment: `<>` is deprecated, use `!=` instead.

Answer (score 3):

raw_input returns a string, so you're getting back `"10"` (according to my terminal).

`10 == '10'` yields false. You need to cast the input to a number.

```
A = int(raw_input("5 + 5 ="))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the result of your call to `raw_input` is a *string,* not an *integer*.

You are comparing `5+5 == "10"`, which is false.

Trying using the [`int("str")` function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int) to convert your input to a number.